# There is only a finite number of interpretations of a wf $\mathcal{B}$ on a domain with cardinality $k$

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

For any wf $\mathcal{B}$, apparently there is only a finite number of interpretations of a wf $\mathcal{B}$ on a domain with cardinality $k \in \mathbb{N}$. But why?

I received the following hint: "
Let's fix a wf $\mathcal{B}$, a number $k \in \mathbb{N}
$ and an interpretation with domain $D$ containing $k$ elements. How many different interpretations of the symbol in the language of $K$ that occur in the wf $\mathcal{B}$ can you have?"

How do I know how many of them? I know that any theory that has a model has a denumerable model (by Skolem-Löwenheim Theorem). But denumerable is not necessarily finite. Should I show by contradiction that $\mathcal{B}$ cannot have infinite interpretations when $D$ is finite?

Comment: There are two key-points here: (i) a formula is a finite expression; thus, we have a finite number of non-logical symbols, e.g. predicate letters. Assume for simplicity there there is only one unary predicate $P$.

Comment: (ii) The predicate $P$ must be interpreted with a subset of the domain $D$. But $D$ is *finite* with $k$ elements; thus, there are $2^k$ subsets. This means: at most $2^k$ different way to interpret $P$.

Comment: The argument is obviously generalized to $n$ predicates (must be finite) with $m$ arguments (again $m$ finite).

Comment: I do understand now. However, how many possible interpretations are there when a wf has a functional letter in it? If a function letter is $f_j^n$ and $M$ is an interpretation, then $(f_j^n)^M$ is a mapping from $D_n$ onto $D$. So, are there $k$ possible interpretations?

Comment: What you call a "wf" ("well-formed formula"?) most people just call a "formula".

Comment: Yep, but wf is quicker to type. That's why I use "wf"

Comment: @VicRyan I would say there are $k^{k^n}$ possible interpretations in that case. For every element in $D^n$ there are $k$ possibilities to be mapped to an element in $D$.